# Should clickable elements in my app always be anchor tags?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on an app and was just thinking about this. What is the point of placing links all over the place and then preventing them from being links? I use a css class namespace for attaching javascript to keep it separate from style. I can tell which elements do JS related things by looking for a class with a preceding underscore.

So if I have a list like this:

(haml)

```
%ul
  %li
    %a._click_event_hook
```

Why not just do this instead?

```
%ul
  %li._click_event_hook
```

Is there any reason other than semantics? Semantically links feel wrong for these kind of elements anyway. It's not a link to another page on the site. It performs an action locally in my application.

Can anyone think of any major disadvantages to this kind of structure in web applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How important these are to your application will vary by the audience and/or goals of the application, but here are a few points to consider.

- graceful degradation - even with Javascript turned off the anchor can/will do something
- focusability - tabIndex="0"
- Accessibility - consider how screen readers and the likes will respond to the elements you create that replicate button/anchor functionality.

You could overcome these and side step link prevention by using `<button />`

Comment: These are things that I've thought about and don't really apply to my application. The application requires JS to function due to design/ux decisions that were made so I'm not worried about that. It's a content management system for photos so not really appropriate for screen readers anyway. The only thing that could be concerning is losing focusability. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: The problem I have with using button is that in the example I posted I still get unnecessary nesting like with <a> tags

Comment: Interesting note HTML5 looks like it is expanding tabindex to include all elements. http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/index.html#attributes-1 and here is a fiddle which shows it working for me in Chrome. http://jsfiddle.net/FtbDq/ so Tab Index may not matter either.